# How to deserialize of json data if one key having data which is directly read from file(non printable characters)

Tags: c#

```
 string jsondata =   {  "class": "MFPUTIL",  "method": "MFPUtilBase64Encode",  "args": {    "value": "%PDF-1.4 Sharp Scanned ImagePDF%Sharp Non-Encryption3 0 obj<</Type /Page/Parent 1 0 R/Resources 4 0 R/Contents 5 0 R/MediaBox [0 0 613 790]>>endobj4 0 obj<</ProcSet [/PDF /ImageB]/XObject << /Img1 6 0 R >>>>endobj5 0 obj<</Length 27>>stream613 0 0 790 0 0 cm/Img1 Doendstreamendobj6 0 obj<</Type /XObject/Subtype /Image/Name /Img1/Filter /CCITTFaxDecode/DecodeParms <<  /K -1 /Columns 1704 /Rows 2196 >>/Width 1704/Height 2196/BitsPerComponent 1/ColorSpace /DeviceGray/Length 7 0 R>>stream_�������W]������}�Y���������W��_����������)�����������������������������������������!|�P!E�;!a̝��0�fC@@ h`�gNKb���@����<&�M�au�D<�;D??KDB:D\"*��?�oA�A����}&�6�;�zo����:o����+�'�m'���������W�Q��C#G���*�`C�xDX��PEx����N�F�Π�0\\�j ���=<q[c��\\ xA��a��M�m��\t��/�^�ڽ�A���Z!0������8\"?������Bg���P�`�?�^\"a�o�,6�> ����� l�PA�&��`�A�>�a�?�uG���_���a{ @0�I��dŲ�����I��؞��'݃I�>�u���{�����ޟ����5��a�������0��^���L������=��YIA����8�Z���"  }
```

Above code is the string data,if we deserialize by below code getting error.

```
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsondata, null).
```

Please provide solution for deserialize json if that string has one non printable value

Comment: Is that you your incoming JSON? Are you sure that value shouldn't have been base64 encoded as the "method" field suggests?

Comment: Anyway., Is this .Net core or .Net Framework 4.x?

Comment: value is not base64 encoded.

Comment: This is .net core

Comment: You can't read that data because it is not JSON. It doesn't comply with the specification: https://www.json.org/json-en.html . No out of the box serializer will work with that example.

Answer (score -1):

From Javascript or client side send data as string using below:

```
var jsondataString = JSON.stringify(jsondata);
```

I think you can convert using below method: (my example)

```
LoginInfo objLoginInfo;
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new 
System.IO.StringReader(jsondataString.ToString()));
reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
objLoginInfo = serializer.Deserialize<LoginInfo>(reader);
```

Suppose here i have class name LoginInfo in which type i want to convert my JSON Object otherwise you can use their `object` type to convert.

Comment: Trying to solve the problem by System.Text.Json , try to not use third party component like newtonsoft

Comment: sorry i am not aware about to solve thing using System.Text.Json but i have solve my problem using newtonsoft easly and conveniently so i have suggested this way